# relation "old" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, triggers

When i try execute this script, i get an error:
ERROR: relation "old" does not exist.
Script:

```
update organization 
set row_status = 30;
```

I found some question like this, but their dont help me.
My trigger:

```
Create OR REPLACE function PMigrateDataToHistory()
returns trigger as $PMigrateDataToHistory$
begin

insert into organization_history
select 
  * 
from 
  OLD;

delete 
from 
  organization as org USING 
  OLD as o
where 
  o.id = org.id and
  o.version = org.version;

insert into organization
select
  n.id,
  n.created_at,
  n.updated_at,
  n.row_status,
  n.version + 1,
  n.resource
from
  NEW as n;
end;

$PMigrateDataToHistory$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER TRMigrateDataToHistory AFTER update or delete ON organization
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE PMigrateDataToHistory();
```

Comment: I don't understand why you delete the row that the delete trigger already deleted (and then re-insert that row **again**). That seems rather strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first `INSERT`, use something like

```
INSERT INTO organization_history VALUES (OLD.*);
```

The `DELETE` and the second `INSERT` are ill-conceived – for one, this will cause a lot of unnecessary churn in the `organization` table.

It would be much better to use a `BEFORE` trigger, add 1 to `NEW.version` and return `NEW`. This would cause the values to be adjusted *before* the record is written to the table.

Answer (score 1):

You are mis-understanding what `OLD` and `NEW` are: those aren't tables, it is the **row** that has been inserted or modified.

However you do not need to delete and insert everything. Just increment the version in a **BEFORE** trigger.

Then you can simplify your trigger to:

```
create or replace function pmigratedatatohistory()
returns trigger as $$
BEGIN
  insert into organization_history values (old.*);
  new.version := new.version + 1; -- increment the version
  return new;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You need a **BEFORE** trigger for that:

```
create trigger trmigratedatatohistory BEFORE update or delete ON organization
    for each row execute procedure pmigratedatatohistory();
```

---

The process when you delete a row doesn't make sense to me. The current code does the following:

1. A `delete from organization` is executed and the row is deleted
2. The trigger makes a copy of that row
3. The trigger tries to delete that row **again** (and does nothing, because it's an `after` trigger, so the row is already gone from the table)
4. The rigger re-inserts the row that should have been deleted with a higher version number - essentially reverting the delete completely.

The same behaviour can be achieved by the simply incrementing the version in the before trigger. If you want to prevent deletion completely simply return `null` in the before trigger:

```
create or replace function pmigratedatatohistory()
returns trigger as $$
BEGIN
  insert into organization_history values (old.*);
  new.version := new.version + 1; -- increment the version
  if TG_OP = 'DELETE' then 
    return null; -- "cancel" the delete 
  else
    return new;
  endif;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Laurenz Albe is right, about using "DELETE" you have to use "BEFORE" not "AFTER"
here are my examples(using postgresql):

```
create table if not exists v08_orders (
order_id serial primary key,
order_date DATE,
customer_name varchar(50));



create table if not exists v08_order_logs(
log_id serial primary key,
order_id INT,
log_date TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
log_text TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES v08_orders (order_id) on delete set null);
```

create or replace function func_delete_order()
returns trigger as $$
begin
insert into v08_order_logs(order_id, log_text)
values(OLD.order_id, 'an order is deleted ar: ' || CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
return OLD;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER order_delete_trigger
before DELETE ON v08_orders
FOR EACH ROW
execute function func_delete_order();
```

so every time you delete an item from the order, before deleting actually happens, an action of adding one log in the order_logs table will be triggered