# Value for all PostgreSQL-trigger rows in an update statement?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, audit, audit-trail

I'm trying to create an update-audit trigger prototype in PostgreSQL. 
I'm logging all modified old values of t_test into t_test_history, as well as the new ones. So far, works perfectly.

But now I want to log the batch id of a update statement for all updated rows in a statement.

Say, I want to run `UPDATE t_test set b = 5 ;` on t_test with 10 entries

What I want, is to assign an id to this "transaction". 
Say, a random integer called __batch_id. 
But if I assign a random number between 1 and 10

```
 __batch_id := floor(random() * (10 + 1));
```

I (unsurprisingly) see that it's a different random number for each row. 
When I want to pass a random-number to execute procedure, I get

> "syntax error at or near "(""

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.log_test(now, random());
```

How can I have such a identifying value without having to pass it to the update-statement from program code, and without having to write it to a temp-table ?
 
Is it possible at all ? 
Bonus points if it would be an auto-increment instead of a random number. 
Also, I'd prefer to do this on a set, instead of on a per-row basis.

This is what I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.log_test()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  __operation_time timestamp without time zone;
  __batch_id int;
BEGIN
 __operation_time := TG_ARGV[0];
 __batch_id := floor(random() * (10 + 1));


 INSERT INTO t_test_history VALUES( __operation_time, user, __batch_id, OLD.*);
 INSERT INTO t_test_history VALUES( __operation_time, user, __batch_id, NEW.*);


 RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;



DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS log_update on "public"."t_test";
CREATE TRIGGER log_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON t_test
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.log_test(now, random()
    );
```

This (T-SQL example) is what I would prefer to have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[issues_trg_update_history] ON [dbo].[TestTable] 
    FOR UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @operation_time AS datetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    DECLARE @operation_uid AS uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable_History 
    SELECT SUSER_SNAME(), 'update-deleted', @operation_time, @operation_uid, * 
    FROM deleted 
    ; 
    INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable_History 
    SELECT SUSER_SNAME(), 'update-inserted', @operation_time, @operation_uid, * 
    FROM inserted 
    ; 
END 

GO

EXEC sp_settriggerorder @triggername=N'[dbo].[issues_trg_update_history]', @order=N'Last', @stmttype=N'UPDATE'
GO
```

Also, is there a specific reason the keyword `now` works, but `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` leads to an error ?

Comment: The problem is getting the same value for all affected rows of an update statement, not inserting that value. And no, you can't select from old.*, it's not a table. That was my first mistake as well, btw. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014052/relation-old-does-not-exist)

Comment: You would need a statement level trigger + plus a row level trigger that stores the affected rows in an intermediate temporary table (currently there is no equivalent for SQL Server's `deleted` "table" in Postgres, that might change with 10.0 though)

Comment: You could use Postgres' internal transaction id: `txid_current()`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Many thanks, that seems to work. Combination of date + txid should be unique.

Comment: Btw: are you aware of this: http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html or this: http://archive.is/DFZP0 ? Those are audit triggers that store the _difference_ between the old and the new values in a hstore or json column (instead of having to create two rows for each modification)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I was aware of hstore, and the possible existance of such a thing. Didn't know it already existed. The link is great, but seems to be more geared towards change-tracking, for display within an application. That is nice too, and I will probably add that as well, but my goal is adding restore functionality for data accidentally deleted/modified by a user. Again, thanks for that as well.

Comment: If that is for some kind of backup, there might be a completely different (and less intrusive) option: logical replication and decoding. You can add a listener to a logical replication slot then get all transaction information and store that "somewhere". That will have much less impact on the server performance. See e.g. here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logicaldecoding-example.html or an example in Java: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html

Comment: You can restore accidentally deleted/modified data by using audit information. You will have access to what data was in before statement got executed. So if you plan to implement it, then adding anything more seems redundant.